# How to make N:N relationship in laravel 4

Tags: laravel

Can anyone help me co build the contact_user ? I need to create two primary keys in this table but, I run this in artisan but does not work. Anybody how to solve this problem?

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function($table){
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name',50);
        $table->date('born');
        $table->string('email');
        $table->timestamps();
    }); 

    Schema::create('contact', function ($t){
        $t->increments('id');
        $t->string('email');
    }); 

    Schema::create('contact_user', function ($t){
        $t->integer('id_user')->primary();
        $t->integer('id_contact')->primary();
        $t->foreign('fk_user')->references('id_user')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
        $t->foreign('fk_contact')->references('id_contact')->on('contact')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
    });
}
```

Comment: You've asked a lot of questions and never marked any as correct? Theres a green tick next to all answers that you are meant to select to help others. Heres a helpful link for you http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

This should work but is not tested.  Most of it was pulled from the docs and pretty straight forward.  I've changed some of the columns to match the naming conventions Laravel is expecting.  This makes life much easier when setting up relations, etc...

Check those out at:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function($table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name',50);
        $table->date('born');
        $table->string('email');
        $table->timestamps();
    }); 

    Schema::create('contacts', function ($t) {
        $t->increments('id');
        $t->string('email');
    }); 

    Schema::create('contact_user', function ($t) {
        $t->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $t->integer('contact_id')->unsigned();
        $t->primary(array('user_id', 'contact_id'));
        $t->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
        $t->foreign('contact_id')->references('id')->on('contacts')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
    });
}
```

Comment: the artisan return this error, but it was builded the tables
  [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]                                                                                                               
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table 'crud.#sql-460_40' (errno: 150) (SQL: alter table `contact_user` add constraint contact_u  
  ser_contact_id_foreign foreign key (`contact_id`) references `contacts` (`id`) on delete cascade on update cascade)

Comment: Which version do you have?  Try the sql `show variables like "%version%";`

Comment: I just ran this on mysql 5.5 and it seems to have worked fine.